# create evenly spaces points with little bit of randomness python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python 3.8

From https://realpython.com/np-linspace-numpy/
it covers creating evenly spread values however I want to add some randomness to it.

say I have range(0, 10) and want to create 3 evenly spread out points(with randomness), w/o randomness I would simply do
`np.linspace(0, 10, 3)` outputting `[0, 5, 10]` but I want it to be spread out like `[1.11, 5.66, 9.33]`, `[0.33, 5.44, 9.33]` and so on... distance between two points do not have to be exact however in case of 3 points it should be 20~30% apart from each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure it's what you want to achieve, but couldn't you just start with normal evenly spaced points and add some jitter afterwards?

Something like (tune *scale* to fit your requirements):

```
np.linspace(0, 10, 3) + np.random.normal(size=3, scale=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but I think this does do what you are asking, though definitely could be improved

```
r = (0,10) ## range 
num = 4 ## number of values

x = np.linspace(r[0],r[1], num+1)
s = x.shape[0] - 1
y = np.zeros(s)
print(x)

for i in range(s):
    low = x[i]
    high = x[i+1]*num/(num+1) ## account for spacing 
    y[i] = np.random.uniform(low=low, high=high, size=(1,1))
    
print(y)
```

**OUT:**

```
[ 0.   2.5  5.   7.5 10. ]
[0.67724968 3.85532474 5.59241682 7.58428896]
```